# Hamster excessively washing her front paws

Tags: behavior, hamsters

My Syrian black bear hamster has lately been washing her front paws and face a lot. Is this because she is nervous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, she just wants to be clean :)

Nervous or scared hamsters will run away, hide, poop themselves, bat your hands or turn on their backs and scream at you if you try to touch them.